# Pyside delay on process exit

Tags: python, pyside6

I have a Windows desktop ([open-source](https://github.com/imubit/qt-data-extractor/)) application developed in Pyside6. I am trying to remove a tooltip delay for a certain widget (a pretty innocent operation) and I am ending up with a huge delay when exiting the application (the process ends a minute after I click on exit).The code I am adding is this:

```
class NoDelayHintProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def styleHint(self, hint, option=..., widget=..., returnData=...):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay:
            return 0

        return QtWidgets.QProxyStyle.styleHint(self, hint, option, widget, returnData)

...

        self._w.comboSampleRate.setToolTip(
            """
            some text
            """
        )

        self._w.comboSampleRate.setStyle(
            NoDelayHintProxyStyle(self._w.comboSampleRate.style())
        )
...
```

I suspect that the problem is not directly related to this code and this code is just a symptom. It feels that an object / or some 3rd party lib thread is not terminated properly on exit.

Is there any simple way to monitor objects, threads termination with Pyside?

- [Full code causing the problem](https://github.com/imubit/qt-data-extractor/compare/main...raw-data-option-by-default)
- Platform: Windows
- Pyside version: 6.4.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The proper way to do it is like the following:

```
class NoDelayHintProxyStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QProxyStyle.__init__(self)

    def styleHint(self, hint, option=..., widget=..., returnData=...):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay:
            return 0

        return QtWidgets.QProxyStyle.styleHint(self, hint, option, widget, returnData)

...

        self._w.comboSampleRate.setToolTip(
            """
            some text
            """
        )

        self._w.comboSampleRate.setStyle(
            NoDelayHintProxyStyle()
        )

...
```

Comment: It's worth noticing that the documentation actually [warns about that](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproxystyle.html#QProxyStyle), even if not as importantly as it probably should: "Ownership of style is transferred to QProxyStyle." This is extremely important, as, by default, a widget always uses the QApplication style, so calling `setStyle(QProxyStyle(self.style()))` will result in the widget's style *owning* the whole current QApplication style **instance**. That can create issues like yours due to object ownership and QObject tree deletion order.

Comment: As a result, the `QProxyStyle(<QStyle>)` syntax should generally be used only when setting the QApplication style. For customizing specific widget behavior, then the safer option is to use `QProxyStyle(QApplication.style().objectName())` or, eventually, use a QApplication wide proxy style and customize the behavior based on the widget class or its properties. For instance, make `comboSampleRate` from a QComboBox subclass (possibly using widget promotion, if creating the UI with Designer), and check `isinstance(widget, <subclass-name>)` to eventually return the different delay.